# Create order for fetching and parsing scripts dynamically

Tags: javascript, performance, asynchronous, dom, browser

I am trying to optimize website with multiple frontend applications. I would like to dynamically download (parse) application and set order for critical application for our system.

I was thinking about `fetchpriority`:

```js
function appendScriptWithPriority(src, priority) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = src;
    script.async = true;
    script.fetchpriority = 'low';

    script.onload = () => {
      resolve();
    };

    script.onerror = (error) => {
      reject(error);
    };

    // Append the script to the head of the document
    document.head.appendChild(script);
  });
}
```

In DOM, I can see script without `fetchpriority`:

```html
<script src='src' async></script>
```

Is there any way, how can I set `fetchpriority` for script dynamically? Or should I go completely different way ?

Comment: why would you want low priority with dynamically added scripts - do you think it will make any difference?

Answer (score 0):

[fetchPriority](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/fetchPriority) is an attribute of [HTMLImageElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement), the [script](https://www.javatpoint.com/html-script-tag) tag does not have such an attribute. `fetchPriority` sets the priority of fetching an image (not of a script) in comparison to other images. So, when you try to set this attribute for a `script` tag, then the browser will have to handle this invalid attribute. One way of handling it is to simply discard the change, as happened in your browser. During your tests you may find a browser that adds this attribute, but the attribute ending up having no effect.

So, the idea should be implemented in a different manner, because this one is invalid. Instead of this, you could create a graph of dependencies.

Make sure that your graph is either a tree or a forest, that is, no cycles are present in there.

The rule of thumb is that a node's loading is a promise that should be execute after all the dependencies' corresponding promises were fulfilled.

So, let's create an array of script setups, like:

```
let myScripts = {
    ["src2"]: {dependencies: [], promise: null},
    ["src3"]: {dependencies: ["src2"], promise: null},
    ["src1"]: {dependencies: ["src2", "src3], promise: null},
};
```

Let's make sure you order these objects into an array, let's call it `arrScripts` in such a manner:

If script1 and script2 are two scripts, then

> arrScripts.indexOf(script1) < arrScripts.indexOf(script2) => myScripts[script1].dependencies.indexOf(script2) === -1

Make sure you are getting the sort right, because this is a [POSET](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/mathematics/partially-ordered-set), scripts not being dependencies either way are not comparable by the rule above.

Now, loop your array and create a `Promise` for all your elements in such a manner that trivial items (those which have no dependencies) will be promises for loading the corresponding script, preferrably being the returned value of a function that looks like `appendScriptWithPriority`, whereas nontrivial items would look like:

```
Promise.all(yourdependencies).then(yourPromise)
```

that is, your script above will not start being loaded until all its dependencies finished loading. So, you will have your mechanism for creating your promises and you can apply them consistently, whereas the difference between trivial and nontrivial promises would be that trivial promises, not having dependencies will be created as promises, whereas nontrivial promises will be a `then` of a `Promise.all`.